# React Native Server - Is Custom Routes / Endpoints possible?

Tags: facebook, reactjs, express, react-native, server

I'm new to mobile development and I know there are some fundamentally different things than the web, so I'm trying to understand RN's server. How does it work? I can't even tell if it is a node server when I look at the source code. What kind of server is it? Does anyone have any resources or high level knowledge of RN's Sever that they could please explain to me?

I'm also wondering if it's possible to create custom routes and endpoints like an express server within React Native. I realize RN doesn't use express. Does anyone have any experience doing that?

The source code is [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/src/AssetServer/index.js) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/src/Server/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

This module is an internal tool and I think it should keep that usage.

If you look at the tests file [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/packager/src/Server/__tests__/Server-test.js), you can see that this server is a part of the Packager and is used to serve several elements:

- Bundle JS
- Assets
- Tools for debugging and hot reload

I don't think it's a good idea to try to use this code inside your React Native app.

Comment: So, I'm looking to hook up mock data by creating routes inside my app. I basically want to hijack the routes my app would normally make outside and keep them inside with mock routes and mock data. Later I would remove these routes or set some sort of env var to do this. Do you think this is possible?